# Cloning ecryptfs drives

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

I have the task of installing Ubuntu on 1600 laptops that need s few folders encrypted using ecryptfs.

I want to configured and encrypt 1 laptop then clone the rest. Will the clones also be encrypted? And is there any downside to this other than all the laptops will have the same 'passphrase'?

Thanks,

@iomari

Comment: @rudib "Changing the passphrase after cloning would of course fix that." Not quite; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the clones will be encrypted. And yes, there is a hidden downside besides all of them sharing the login passphrase (the one you usually type when you log in, and which you can change): they'll also share the mount passphrase (i.e., the encryption master key, which you don't normally see or interact with yourself, and that you can't change without re-encrypting). This means that even after the users change their passphrases, it will forever be possible for any user to decrypt any other user's data.